# "play a friend" Is this expression natural?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I recently knew expressions "play the victim", "play the fool", "play innocent".
In this context, is **"play a friend"** natural, meaning **"to fabricate a friendship**, and pretend as if one and his opponent were friendly"? If not, what's an alternative phrase to this meaning?

Comment: It would have to be *You don't have to play **the** friend with me*, but in practice no-one would be likely to say it anyway. To *play the **victim / fool / innocent*** are all idiomatically valid - the article being required with the first two, but optional in [***Don't play innocent with me**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22don%27t+play+innocent+with%22) It's not really a "productive" construction though, so if you can't find lots of written instances online, avoid inventing new versions for any given noun you might be thinking of.

Comment: Offhand I can't think of any idiomatic expression meaning "don't pretend to be my friend when you're not really". We have things like *Don't [try to] flatter / toady / suck up to me / curry favour / ingratiate yourself with me*. But the "pretend to be my friend" aspect is usually just ***implicit*** in those alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should make sure to use something common . Also perhaps the concept "a fake friendship" isn't so usual in English culture, I guess.

Comment: "curry favour" That's quite an amusing idiom.

Comment: @최강러브라이브 It's very close to :"curry flavour", a very different thing.

Comment: “Play a friend” is an usual but acceptable idiom. You may need some supporting information to make your meaning clear to those who don’t immediately get your intended message.

Comment: @최강러브라이브: I've always known and used the expression, but I only found out about the fascinating etymology today - from good ole Merriam-Webster... *The idiom **curry favor** is an alteration by folk etymology of **curry favell**, Middle English **core favele, currey favel** "to use insincere flattery to gain personal advantage," literally, "to curry the fallow-colored horse," a translation of Middle French **estriller/torchier Fauvel** "to use trickery, deceive," literally, "**to curry/clean Fauvel**" ("the fallow one," as a name for a horse).*

Comment: Another extremely common "animal-based" idiomatic usage in this general area is *He tried to [**worm his way into her affections.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22worm+his+way+into+her+affections%22) (That one was just too long to fit in previous comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

“Play a friend” doesn’t make sense to me. I would just say something like “you call me a friend (but you’re not really)” or  “you only pretend to be my friend.”

There is a slang term “frenemy” (a portmanteau of friend and enemy) that can be used to indicate someone who acts like a friend but isn’t really, but this wouldn’t be appropriate for formal speech.

A similar (but not identical) term would be a “fair-weather friend” - someone who acts like a friend when things are going well, but not when things are going badly.

Answer (score 0):

'Play the friend' is not a recognisable idiom.

Expressions like 'play the victim' and 'play the fool' relate to *theatre*. The 'fool' is a recurring character type in many classic plays, such as the works of William Shakespeare. In dramas, there are usually characters such as the victim, antagonist and hero. Actors 'play' these parts. As an idiom, 'play the victim' means that someone feigns hurt in order to heap blame on someone else. Interestingly, Psychologist Stephen B. Karpman proposed that, in real-life 'dramas', there is always a victim, a perpetrator and a rescuer, and that whenever someone plays one of these parts, the other two emerge.

In that literal context of acting, you might well hear someone say something like "*in this production, I play the friend*", but it is not recognisably an idiom for a 'fake friend'. There are countless other nouns and adjectives for someone like that, including 'backstabber' or 'disingenuous'.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this construction may be used that way and understood by many English speakers. There may be regions where it does not have wide acceptance. In this context "**play**" means "**pretend to be**".

There is also an idiom in some regions "play" which means to take advantage of someone or deceive someone to get rewards. Saying "he played you" means "he tricked you". Saying "he plays people" means "he manipulates people". There are other ways to use this as well. A person who plays others is a "player".